# CocoaPods missing framework causing a "linker command failed" error

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, frameworks, cocoapods

I'm using **XCODE 7.1**. Trying to add [this library](https://github.com/pusher-community/pusher-websocket-swift) to my **existing Swift** project, I've made the following pod file:

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!
pod 'PusherSwift'
```

Since installing this, my project throws the following error when trying to build:

> ld: framework not found CryptoSwift
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I can't import the required library. and I also have a red (missing) framework named **Pods_myProject.framework**

How can I fix it?

Comment: You are opening the yourProject.xcworkspace instead of the yourProject.xcodeproj, right?

Comment: Oh god, thank you for that

Comment: I've added an answer cause it was what I supposed it was! Glad it helped :) Please accept the answer I've just posted so the question gets 'closed'

Comment: Note on CryptoSwift: It is 500 to 1000 times slower than Apple's supplied Common Crypto and my have security issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After installing pods you need to make sure to open the Xcode workspace (yourProject.xcworkspace) instead of the project (yourProject.xcodeproj) when building your project.

See [CocaPods](https://cocoapods.org/) page for more info.